# Macbook: Other Storage Growing at Insane Rates

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, storage

I have an Early 2015 Macbook Pro Retina running Big Sur 11.2.3 that has been acting up lately. Essentially my "Other" storage is growing at insane rates. After rebooting, I have 145GB free on my HD free. Doing nothing, the "Other" storage grows and eventually brings me to less than 100mb in like 1.5-2 hours.

I can't even backup using Time Machine. The back up says "Preparing backup" basically until my storage on my HD runs out (1.5-2 hours). Here's a few notes:

- I've unchecked "Back up automatically" on Time Machine
- I've tried "tmutil listlocalsnapshots /" and "tmutil deletelocalsnapshots /", however, after unchecking the "Back up automatically" the localsnapshot is not created.
- My external harddrive that I'm trying to backup to has 500+ GB free.
- I've deleted every pending backup that I can find.
- **I've downloaded DaisyDisk and found that the folder that in increasing non-stop in size is: /private/var/folders/zz/(long name)/T. I can't see inside the folder, so I have no idea what it is. But that folder definitely seems to be my problem.**

What can I do? I'm getting desperate and feeling hopeless. I've read every forum/reddit post I could find but nothing seems to be working. Which files should I manually save if I try wiping my mac?

This is my wife's computer she uses for work and she is currently having to restart the device every 1.5-2 hours because otherwise she is unable to do anything (due to the low storage). Any help would be very much appreciated.